# What are some of the problems with the view that light is a disturbance of the ether?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, aether

There is a view that was held by Nikola Tesla, that light does not consist of photons, but is a disturbance of the ether - the same way sound is a disturbance of the atmosphere - and that the speed of light is the actually the maximum rate of induction.

Where would this model be lacking, apart from the obvious fact that the ether is not considered to be factual?

Comment: Apparently Tesla did not believe in special or general relativity, which are both (now) well tested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Comment: So how does he explain that there a no longitudinal polarisations (aka pressure waves)? Does he just claim that it follows exactly Maxwell equations or is there anything more to the model. If exactly the same, then it is just an untestable hypothesis and was eliminated by Occams razor.

Answer (score 3):

If light were a real wave in a real ether, similar to water waves or sound waves, we would find that the measured speed of light depends on whether the earth, in its orbit around the sun, is travelling with or against the light's motion.

[Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) allow you to calculate the speed of electromagnetic waves from the permittivity and the permeability of free space. The speed and direction of the earth's movement do not appear in the calculation, implying that the speed of the wave is independent of the earth's movement. The calculated result accurately matches the measured speed of light, proving that light is a form of electromagnetic waves.

The [Michelson–Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) proved the speed of earth through the ether is not measurable. Regardless of the direction of the earth's movement, the measured speed of light stays exactly the same.

Einstein used the fixed speed of light as the starting point for his theory of Special Relativity. This theory and its extension, the Theory of General Relativity, have been [thoroughly tested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) many times in the past century, and so far have been found to perfectly agree with our measurements.

As a result, we can say that light can definitely not be treated as a wave in a material.

Comment: Would not the same apply to photon particles? If you are moving towards them, then you will reach them faster than if you are moving away from them, even if the difference in time is incredibly small in the case of planetary movement?

Comment: No. That's why relativity is important.

Comment: @Carl photons=light, so their speed in vacuum is always c